# ASP.NET MVC - setting a cookie not working in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set a cookie when my user logs in.  The cookie works on Safari, but on Chrome it isn't showing up in the Storage / Cookies section.

What am I doing wrong?

In the AccountController I have the following:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    //create a cookie
                    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("site");

                    //Add key-values in the cookie
                    myCookie.Values.Add("test", "test value");
                    myCookie.Domain = "local";
                    myCookie.Path = "/";

                    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

                    Response.AppendCookie(myCookie);
                    return RedirectToLocal(ReturnUrl);
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Update - if I remove the domain, then the cookie starts working in Chrome (but can't be shared)

Comment: "local" doesn't seem like a valid domain. Are you trying to share the cookie locally, or on the "live" site? If you're trying to share it across subdomains, you need something like ".yourdomain.tld" - with the leading period.

Comment: trying to share it locally on my development machine - one domain is xyz.local the other is abc.local

Comment: Take a look at these links : https://forums.asp.net/t/2047114.aspx?How+to+set+cookie+path+in+asp+net+mvc   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654536/programmatically-set-cookie-domain-per-user-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Btw @TiesonT. , the leading period isn't required

Comment: @RobbieMills Interesting. MDN agrees with you. Seems like I always needed the leading period for it to work on our sites. Learn something new every day, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue thanks to @tiesonT.  .local is a restricted domain name for Chrome when saving cookies.  The code works well in staging/prod, but for development I had to change to a different non generic domain name.

This only appears to be an issue for Chrome