# Asp .net does not writes cookies on the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpcookie

I am trying to write a cookie into the browser using HttpCookie, the following is my approach

```
        private async Task WriteCookie (string userName) {

            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, cookiesIdentity);

            TokenResult token = await AuthenticationHelper.GetBearerTokenAsync(Request, user.UserName, user.Password);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(".myCookie");
            cookie.Value = token.access_token;
            cookie.Domain = ".myDomain"
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "App");

        }
```

I have read a lot of posts but none of the solutions works for my case, it's worth to mention that I have tried:

1. to remove the domain part of the cookie.
2. add the following settings to web.config

   ```
   <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
   ```
3. Run my sites over https

EDIT

I traced my app requests using fiddler and I notice that this request does set the response header with set-cookie param however when it redirects to the dashboard the cookie disappears from the browser.

I hope you guys can give me some clue to solve this.

SOLVED

While debugging this method a figured out that token.access_token coming as null so the value of the cookie was set to null, so when the browser redirects to the dashboard it was deleting the cookie because its value was null, I checked the process that generates the tokens and it had a problem, I fixed it and everything started working again. thanks

Comment: May a local host issue but will work on a public domain https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560773/10634638

Comment: No, I set my host file with my domain in order to avoid that problem

Comment: I don’t know if it will help if you are still on your local IP address.. Redirecting can be a problem when setting a cookie too, use a session variable..